# Pluralizaciones rotas en Transifex

Tags: soporte, traducciones, transifex

Ojalá esto sea alguna estupidez de mi parte, que no estoy viendo algo, o estoy interpretando algo mal...

#### 1. Desaparecieron algunas pluralizaciones

Estaba revisando un término que traduje hace algunos días:

> Of the votes cast, *`$up$`* were up-votes and *`$down$`* were down-votes. `$DisplayName$` voted on questions *`$q$`* times and *`$a$`* times on answers.
>
> ---
>
> Transifex: [LINK](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/134794816?key=b6475232202bb96802a83f457ea79900)

Y veo que todas las formas de pluralización **están igual** (mal). Es decir que las 16 (2^4) sugerencias de ese mismo *Key* dicen todas por igual:

> ```
> De los votos emitidos, _$up$_ fue a favor y _$down$_ fueron en contra. $DisplayName$ votó _$q$_ veces en preguntas y _$a$_ veces en respuestas.
> ```

Pero estoy **totalmente convencido** de que traduje las 16 formas, y sé que me tomé el tiempo de ver que coincidan con el singular/plural para cada caso.

O sea, que iban cambiando entre `fue`/`fueron` y `vez`/`veces`, pero no están más así. Transifex o, más probablemente, SO me está haciendo parecer un tonto que no sabe distinguir entre singular y plural.

Y en Transifex aparece como que la propuse hace 4 días, cuando en realidad la había propuesto aproximadamente el 1/2 (hace 15 días).

¿Alguien puede explicarme qué pasó y confirmar que no estoy loco (al menos no en esto específicamente)?

#### 2. Otras cadenas también desaparecieron

Tratando de ver qué había pasado, busqué en el historial, revisé comentarios dentro de Transifex, y me encontré con los comentarios en los que me nombraron:

> [image: notificaciones en Transifex]
>
> Donde cada `string` tiene un enlace a:
>
> - https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/131532786 **(no existe)**
> - <sup><sub>https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/40283690/ (OK, este está bien)</sub></sup>
> - https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/40283261 **(no existe)**
> - https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/132606410 **(no existe)**

3 de esos 4 comentarios (que apuntaban a cadenas a las que les dediqué tiempo) no están más.

Ahora bien, es normal que algunas cadenas desaparezcan, pero si mal no recuerdo, esas cadenas que comentamos eran cadenas "*históricas*" del sitio, y que no tendrían que estar cambiando, o al menos no **tantas**. Por ejemplo, [la primera](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/131532786) era la discutida en [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1920/127), referida a la cadena `I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because` que sigue exactamente igual en SO, pero que ahora aparece en Transifex [acá](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/134968789?key=5d9e56f7d5348212fa47070a7d735a5f), propuesta por g3rv4, sin todo el historial que tenía, sin la sugerencia previa de fedorqui. El ID de esa cadena ahora es mucho mayor (131M -> 134M), por lo que asumo que es nueva.

No tengo idea si hay forma de buscar las otras que traduje, pero puedo extrapolar una situación similar.

---

Entonces -y, de nuevo, espero que sea estupidez mía y esté completamente equivocado-, ¿Jugaron intentando arreglar el bug y tocaron algo que no había que tocar? ¿Vieron algún conflicto entre la base y Transifex y volvieron a un back-up anterior? ¿Es algo que yo no estoy contemplando? ¿Qué pasó hace 4 días?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Desaparecieron algunas pluralizaciones

Hace 4 días se hizo un cambio en la forma en la que se ordenan las variantes. Ahora, el orden de las distintas variables es el mismo que en la cadena (lo que hace más fácil la traducción).

Esto "rompió" 18 cadenas. Esto quiere decir: siguen estando en la base de datos, pero el sufijo de la key fue modificado... y eso hizo que Transifex aplicara una traducción a todas las variantes y dejara las demás como sugerencias.

Las cadenas afectadas que ya estaban traducidas siguen estando bien en la base de datos (por lo que no se destraducen en el sitio), aunque las traducciones en transifex pueden ser incorrectas.

Estos son los `key`s de las cadenas afectadas:

```
03da42a58795142f23ede4b02efbedd8
0b81d744f1eb1787b016126b6d5d6b34
0e868a8fa494c895de3090e7c8ac428d
0f1028b04314c54113c9382356dabd6c
26459b8c977c85b8e8a6493dd094154a
2e65f1bbce231476e732eb6e3ebc0e56
36604f58571398c045eaa41285efad68
6a7a9d6f3b959c3ec5b6e61fefbed68f
6b0d6ca383ca42c04a7dbc18231d80bb
796138fbac2cc1045a49351cfcf876d7
8be4b5404852718568fadc1ad5672a6a
930bf60fabb24d48556af3936c0aa41d
a96bdb65d7fd5c798bf0347cba2ee68d
ad5615f677f0ff088f4f03301806c757
b6475232202bb96802a83f457ea79900
c1ab4e949cd1853ae3ddc2d21ce42afd
e39b362eccc2425b04d9ef53ad0a9c27
ec0919a19b1ef27f2da6f9f088966e7c
```

### 2. Otras cadenas también desaparecieron

Miré la que mencionás que traduje yo (me imagino que alguien había dejado una sugerencia?) y busqué dónde aparece en el código... encontré este cambio reciente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo que parece que la cadena anterior tenía un espacio al final que fue eliminado. Por eso es considerado una cadena distinta. No estoy al tanto de que tengamos una forma de acceder a las traducciones de las cadenas eliminadas.

Comment: Sobre 2, parece que este espacio final va introduciéndose y quitándose cada cierto tiempo. Viene de [este reporte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1920/83). De ahí que sugiriéramos una cadena con un espacio final, que hizo que en un momento dado hubiera dos espacios finales.

Comment: @fedorqui interesante! de hecho, la sugerencia que aprobé tiene un espacio al final, y por eso si hoy vas a cerrar una pregunta por off topic, te salen dos espacios al final. Corrijo la traducción, porque el espacio se está agregando en ese textarea después de usar el texto traducido.

Comment: @fedorqui estamos discutiendo esta respuesta en https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42896675#42896675

Comment: @Mariano y g3rva relevante: m0sa da por solucionado el tema en [Already translated strings have lost their translations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307134/209901) y [Translations are not used from Transifex for localized sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307136/209901)

Comment: @fedorqui lo sé.. estaba hablando de eso con NicolasChabanovsky en https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42937086#42937086 ;-)

Comment: @Mariano oh, ahora veo tu comentario, no me avisó. Veo pues que Nicolas y [su superping](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42934659#42934659) tuvieron efecto cuasi inmediato :)

Comment: @fedorqui el tiempo desde que un CM interesado se involucra hasta que un dev cierra el tema en MSE estaría rondando las 4hs. :-P